# Downloading 1000 images asynchronously and doing caching but its giving memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a code to download around 1000 images and also performing caching using `NSCache` and showing images in `UICollectionView`. It works but when UICollectionView is scrolled very fast and internet is slow memory warning is received. So what can be the issue here? Below is my code : Thanks in advance.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      ProductCollectionViewCell *cell = (ProductCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

      //set image,title of product
      cell.productLabel.text = [self.productNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      UIImage *image = [self.imgCache getCachedImageForKey:[self.imgUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      if (image.size.width>0) {
        [cell.productImage setImage:image];
      }
      else {
        [cell.productImage setImage:nil];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.imgUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        [cell.productImage setImage:nil];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (imgData!=nil) {
                [cell.productImage setImage:img];
                [self.imgCache cacheImage:img forKey:[self.imgUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                if ([self.imgDataArray count] <= [self.productNameArray count]) {
                    [self.imgDataArray addObject:imgData];
                }
            }
        });
        if ([self.imgDataArray count] == [self.productNameArray count]){
            [self.productsView.collectionView reloadData];
        }
    });    
}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to make UIImageView Category file for download the image from url and it will save the file in the cache memory of the device and when you want to load that image again than it will load that image from cache memory.Here is the link of my code for this [Dowinload Image and store in the cache using category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36354866/4531344)

Answer (score 0):

Use `SDWebImage` framework. 
Below is link or how to link it with project:
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Below is line of code for how to download image using `SDWebImage`.

```
[cell.itemimage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loadingImage"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    cell.itemimage.image = image;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    });
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting data from url and calling imageWithData inside cellForItemAtIndexPath doesn't seem to be good. While the image is not cached, it will try to get the data each time the cell is called which is not a suggested approach rather. Get the image data in an outside function and reload the table view or the corresponding row only.

Try something like this

```
- (void)downloadImages {
    for (int i = 0; i < self.imgUrlArray.count; i++) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){
            NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.imgUrlArray objectAtIndex:i]]];

            if(imgData) {
                UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

                if(img) {
                    // Cache image
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        // reload collection view
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So in your cellForItemAtIndexPath method you only have to do this

```
if (image) {
        [cell.productImage setImage:image];
      }
      else {
[cell.productImage setImage:nil];
}
```